# Content Selection and Mouse Right-click commands not working on Edge, Chrome, Firefox Browsers for specific websites

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I need to routinely select and copy text and images from browser windows for personal use when navigating articles on the Web.

For some **inconsiderate** reason, Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, and Firefox does not let me right-click and Copy, "Save As..." any content, images, or links ANYWHERE on certain sites.  The ability to select text directly, and right-click "Save As..." on images is gone.

For example: [Stray Kids’ Lee Know And Hyunjin Show Their Mature Sides In Interview And Pictorial With Arena Homme](https://www.hellokpop.com/fashion/stray-kids-lee-know-hyunjin-arena-homme-interview/).

In fact, ALL Mouse Right-click Menu behaviors are gone!!

If I go to other websites such as Wikipedia.org, I can select content, but not K-POP sites (see link above) to help my daughter with her homework.  It appears that the perhaps the website publisher is controlling the ability to select content.

I can open the Developer Tools to select whatever I need, such as headlines, images or other content displayed in my browser.  However, I should not have to switch browsers to capture content.  I can switch to a version of Firefox and select the content I need for her homework.  My daughter does not know how to install Firefox or use the browser Developer Tools, nor should she have to!

This behavior is really unacceptable!  This will force me switch away from Firefox and Chrome to "alt-browsers" that remain open and keep data free and open for personal uses.

Disabling right-click functionality on published articles is one of the most USER-UNFRIENDLY actions any developer or publisher can perpetrate!  It violates the United States Fair Use Doctrine for personal use of any content covered by US Federal Copyright Law.

> Fair use is a doctrine in United States law that permits limited use
> of copyrighted material without having to first ethically acquire
> permission from the copyright holder. Fair use is one of the
> limitations to copyright intended to balance the interests of
> copyright holders with the public interest in the wider distribution
> and use of creative works by allowing as a defense to copyright
> infringement claims certain limited uses that might otherwise be
> considered infringement. [Fair Use Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)

I have looked in the Settings but cannot find anything related to selection content or Mouse Right-click Menu behaviors.

How do I change the configuration of Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Firefox other browsers to disable this restriction to restore standard browser functionality for all content on all pages?

Comment: I test the website in Edge, Chrome and Firefox, the issue exists on all the browsers. Choose and right-click doesn't work in all browsers on the page you provide. I think that's not Edge's issue because all the browsers have the same behavior and other websites work well. I think that's the website's source code which makes restriction on the choose and right-click function.

Comment: So how do I fix it?  The data is there being displayed.  I need to disable this unfriendly behavior?  I noticed the problem first in Microsoft Edge, then found it to be a problem with Chrome and Firefox.  I need to disable it and get full access to all text and image content.

Comment: The behavior is website related. Please check my answer below about how to enable selecting and right-clicking. It works for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with any browser. There's some JavaScript and CSS on the website which block the select and right-click function.

If you open F12 devtools to check the CSS of the website, you'll find some styles like `user-select: none;`. The [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) CSS property controls whether the user can select text. And there might be other codes which also prevent selecting.

[image]

For this situation, I think there's no easy way to enable selecting on the website. If you want to enable it, you'll also need to use F12 devtools. I find a way to enable selecting on the website, you can refer to the following steps:

1. Disable JavaScript of the website in Edge: You can click the lock icon on the address bar -> click **Permissions for this site**.

[image]

2. On the **Settings** page, set **JavaScript** to **block**.

[image]

3. Refresh the page to update the settings.
4. Open F12 devtools on the page, paste and run the following code in console:

   ```
   let style = document.createElement('style');
   style.innerHTML = '*{ user-select: auto !important; }';
   document.body.appendChild(style);
   ```

[image]

5. Then you can select and right-click on the page.

[image]

Comment: This is great answer.  I will try it.  Does this have to be done on a per-website basis?  Can this be scripted and automated ONCE for ALL websites?

Comment: It depends. On some websites, you only need to disable JavaScript in browser settings, then you can select & right-click. On some websites, you only need to run the JavaScript code to change the `user-select` value. In this situation, you can run the scripts automatically on these websites through browser extension like **tampermonkey**. But on the website you provide, it needs both. I think there's no automatic way for this kind of websites.